# Google Sheets: If column A contains a value also found in column B, output text string to column C (on the same line as value in column A)

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Exactly as the heading says
I have two columns of data, if the second column contains any data (exact match) also found in the first, output string "found" in third column (on the same line as the data in the first column)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTWe0ZHuR1L8dARtsWLMekQmoP6Cx3RCubFpD12SPrk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A=B2:B; C2:C; ))
```

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, G:H, 2, 0))="",,"found"))
```

Comment: I entered this into column C and got the circular dependency error 
Copied it into column D and nothing changed

Comment: @JTOP can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: i've added the sheet to the initial questions and here. I just want to update allthe location field in the first tab, for all the assets that also appear in the second tab https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTWe0ZHuR1L8dARtsWLMekQmoP6Cx3RCubFpD12SPrk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JTOP sheet is private

Comment: have updated, sorry

Comment: @JTOP try: `=INDEX(IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, G:H, 2, 0))="",,"found"))` the red cell in your sheet

Comment: That's done it! Thanks v much