# Google Sheets - Get value of column C to be placed in column B if value in column A is present in column D

Tags: google-sheets

As the title says, I need to get the value of column C to be placed in column B if the value in column A is present in column D.
Column A contains Jira project names, column D contains the same list of names but mixed up with other project names, and column C contains the dates in which the projects in column D have been last updated.
I need the projects in column A to get the date present in column C if they match their names with the projects in column D

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861398/google-sheets-if-column-a-contains-a-value-also-found-in-column-b-output-text), but this person needed to print "found" if there was a match. I need the date to be printed in column B if there is a match.

Thanks in advance

**Adding an image**: In red I marked the matching project names in columns D and A. In green I marked the date I need to get. The desired output is the date in blue (taken from column C), added to column B, that is placed next to the matching project name in column A.
[image: google sheet sample]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @player0, I just added an image with the desired output

Answer (score 0):

use in B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {D:D, C:C}, 2, 0)))
```